# Integrate Janrain API to android application

Tags: android

I'm trying integrate janrain API to my android applicaion. There is an iPhone library provided by Janrain. If anybody knew how to do this, please help.

Comment: Accept some of your answered questions if you want people to continue helping you.

Answer (score 1):

JanRain has an Android library.  I've recently implemented it as it met my requirements quite nicely.  Authentication is a bit slow, but not enough to walk away from it.

Here's a link to the QuickStart for Android page:  https://rpxnow.com/docs/android#quick

Comment: Aloha code can u please tell me how to use this i mean i have to use this as an Library project ?? i am bit confused